# pdftotext converts spaces to percents and dashes to sixes

Tags: linux, pdf

pdftotext somehow converts all space characters (" ") to percent signs ("%"), and all dashes ("-") to sixes ("6") for a specific pdf.

Any idea how to prevent this behavior? Or how to diagnose this?

Unfortunately I cannot share the pdf at the moment. This might make it too difficult to answer the question. But maybe someone can make a good guess anyway, based on these weird character replacements.

pdftotext version 0.26.5

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A359307+%5Bpdf%5D+text relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess: This PDF uses a funny font, which actually contains spaces (normally, spaces are done by positioning characters), and has a special form of dash. These two glyphs occupy the two positions in the special font where `%` and `6` are in other fonts.

`pdftext` doesn't know anything about this, it just sees "place this glyph from this font here" (because that's how a PDF file looks like), so it assumes wrongly it's text.

Diagnosis: Use `mutool` from the `mupdf` package (or some other tool) to decompress the streams, open the result in a text editor that can handle large files if necessary (e.g. emacs), look at how the page is rendered. Google for the PDF spec if you want to understand more details about how PDFs are rendered.

Alternatively: Extract fonts from the PDF, look if one of the fonts has two glyphs as described.

Comment: This is probably it. Copy and pasting of the text also copies the % and 6 signs. Searching a piece of text requires searching for the %.